# How can a batch file call another batch file?

Tags: path, batch-file

I have two different batch files at two different path. When I call A.bat from B.bat, the batch file that i called(A.bat) doesn't work. When i double click to A.bat it works fine. I think the problem is **the path**. However, I always use full paths. Why it doesn't work?
All i want is to extract my file.

B.batch

```
call "C:\Documents and Settings\A.bat"
```

A.batch

```
SET earfile="E:\bee\deployments\sny1\SnyEarTest.ear"
SET winrar_exe="C:\.....\winrar.exe"
SET war_file="C:\...."

%winrar_exe% e -o+ %earfile% %war_file%
```

When i extract my war_file from the path that A.bat exist then my war_file is extracted into path B. Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Your syntax works for me, just tried it with:
call "C:\temp\New folder\a.bat"

Comment: You could add cd %~dp0 to the A.bat, perhaps winrar can't create a temporary file at the other location

Comment: I had already added cd %~dp0 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

Add `pause` to the end of `B.bat` so you can see any error messages before the window closes.

add a cd /d path at the top of B.bat to specify the folder in which the EAR file is decompressed.

Comment: What happens is when i extract my war_file then it goes to path B. A.bat works at another path but it extracts into path B. Do you have any solutions

Comment: add a `cd /d path` at the top of `B.bat` to specify the folder in which the EAR file is decompressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `A.bat`:

```
...
%winrar_exe% e -o+ %earfile% %war_file% "%~dp0"
```